# The use the special ? variable Netlogo what is the Alternative?

Tags: netlogo

The use of the special ? variable which takes the values of each of the items in the list as we iterate over the list.
what is the alternative use in the new version of NetLogo software???

Comment: see https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#changes-for-netlogo-60

Answer (score 2):

The new [arrow syntax](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#arrow) was introduced with [NetLogo 6](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#changes-for-netlogo-60). Instead of just referring things as `?`, this allows you to actually name your variables:

```
foreach [ 0 1 2 3 ] [ x ->
  print x
]
```

This also allows you to nest these types of blocks and still refer to all the values:

```
foreach [ 0 1 2 3 ] [ x ->
  foreach [ 4 5 6 7 ] [ y ->
    print x + y
  ]
]
```

Previously, you would have to do this with, for instance, `let x ?`. With primitives like `map` and `filter`, you couldn't do this at all, so it's a big improvement. Note that, if you have more than one variable, you have to wrap the arguments with []:

```
(foreach [0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7] [ [x y] ->
  print x + y
])
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer above , but suppose I have a list of boolean values i.e, observer> ask pharmacists [   show ( map > (add-on-prob) ( m ) )]
(pharmacist 31): [true true true true true true false true true true true true false true] and I want to iterate at each value to perform an if statement if it was true [ do something ] and if it was false [ do something else ] how can I achieve this best regards

Comment: @MohammadDawodieh please open a new question to ask this.